# Can't view pdf after compiling

Tags: errors, pdf, compiling, texmaker

EDIT: I solved this by replacing 'figure' with 'figure*'. Thank you all for your input.

I'm using Texmaker and MiKTeX on Windows 10. The file compiles without any issues but the pdf isn't available. When trying to open it with Texmaker, I receive the message: "Error: File not found". When opening the pdf manually with Adobe Acrobat it reads: "Adobe Reader could not open … because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn’t correctly decoded)."

I know for certain that this is due to the figure I tried to add to the text. If I remove the `\includegraphics{}` command and compile again, I can view the pdf.

Here's the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/dawid/Documents/figures} }
```

And the code with which I tried to add the figure:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{lipsum}
\end{figure}
```

There is a .jpg file in the /figures folder. I tried replacing it with a .eps file, reinstalling Texmaker, and refreshing file name databases in MiKTeX, unsuccessfully.

I also receive the message that fixltx2e isn't required, but removing `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` doesn't make a difference.

Edit:
I tried making a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/dawid/Documents/figures} }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{lipsum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here I noticed the file doesn't actually look for the image in /figures but in the folder the .tex file is in. Nonetheless, if I place the image in that folder, I can view it correctly in the pdf with the code above, so I can work with that. However, I want the text to display in two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/dawid/Documents/figures} }

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{lipsum}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Here the file complies and I can view the pdf, but it's completely empty. It seems as if 'multicol' messes with 'figure'.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you perhaps try `\graphicspath{{C:/Users/dawid/Documents/figures}}`, i.e. slashes instead of `\ `?

Comment: I did just that, still can't view the pdf.

Comment: A side note, there is no need for `Figure 1`. inside the `caption`. Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ?

Comment: @BambOo should be better now.

Comment: @Daphne, not really. please merge your code snippets into one complete document, which we can copy in our computers and test as it is.

Comment: @Zarko is it fine now?

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem, answer it yourself! It's much better than giving the solution in the question.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer